# How to clone a object with primary key in Realm.io (objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

i have an object model, with a primary key and i want to do a clone of that object with another primary key but realm.io says "this object already exist "
the primary key is not the same as the first object

```
  RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
  [realm beginWriteTransaction];

  ActivityTreeModel *originalActivity = [ActivityTreeModel objectForPrimaryKey:activityUuid];
  ActivityTreeModel *cloneActivity = originalActivity;
  NSString *primaryKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@+%@",[originalActivity uuid], executionUuid ];

  @try {
       cloneActivity.uuid = primaryKey;
       cloneActivity.execution_uuid = executionUuid;
  }
  @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"error de realm %@",exception);
  }
  @finally {

  }

  [ActivityTreeModel createOrUpdateInRealm:realm withValue:cloneActivity];
  [realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new `ActivityTreeModel` object: `[[ActivityTreeModel alloc] init]`, and then set all it's properties as to the one you want to copy, but with the different primary key.

Comment: but i have to do cloneActivity = originalActivity; cause i want the same as the original but with a new primary key or i have to set all properties one by one from the original activity?

Comment: is working fine with cloneActivity = originalActivity; with your answer creating a new object with a new primary key!